# Differential graded algebra homomorphisms to their base field equipped with the trivial differential

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say we have a differential graded algebra $(A, \delta)$ where $A$ is an algebra over the field $F$. Furthermore, assume that $\delta$ has degree $-1$. Thus we have $A = \oplus_{k=1} A_k$ and if $a_k \in A_k$ then $\delta a_k \in A_{k-1}$

We can turn $F$ into a differential graded algebra by giving it the trivial differential, which we will denote by $0$, so that $0 f = 0 $ for all $f \in F$

Now, I want to better understand the restrictions on differential graded homomorphism $\epsilon: (A,\delta) \rightarrow (F,0)$

I'm under the impression that for any homogeneous element $a \in A$ with degree degree not $0$, ($|a| \neq 0$), then we have $\epsilon(a)=0$. This aparently follows from the fact that $\epsilon$ is degree preserving.

Can somebody help me understand what is going on here? Surely all elements of $(F,0)$ are degree $0$. So, for the sake of contradiction, say $a \in A$ and $|a|=2$. What would go wrong if $\epsilon(a) \neq 0$?

Thank you for your time

Comment: The grading is part of the structure of a differential _graded_ algebra, so it makes sense for maps to preserve that structure. It is not quite accurate to say that all elements of F (as a DGA) are in degree zero, we need a group in each grading level, so $F_2=0$ (the zero group, which does have an element!). In this case, you can see why $\epsilon(a) = 0$ if $a$ is in degree 2.

Comment: Thank you sir!!